# send data from page1 to page2 and save it

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I just want to know how to use SharedPrefreneces to pass data from page1 to page2 and save the data in page2.

I tried this code:

In page 1:

```
String strSource = source1.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("sourceText",strSource);
editor.commit();
```

Page 2:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String defaultValue = "DefaultValue";
String sourceText = sharedPreferences.getString("sourceText",defaultValue);
source1.setText(sourceText);
```

Comment: Pref save data. If you uninstall your app or clear pref then it's clear. you don't want to pass one screen to other screen. you just save and use in all screen

Comment: Reformatted code and fixed spelling error.

Comment: @MR.K can you please tell what is the code?

Comment: @HamzaDev Please follow this link may be it's help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from page1 to page2 then it is possible via intent.

Example: In Kotlin

```
    val intent =Intent(this,Page2Activity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("key","data")
    startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: yeah I know , but I want to know how to save data after passing it

Comment: @HamzaDev Then save it when you got it back from intent.

Comment: String data = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");